# What are the (dis)advantages of parents and children sharing a bedroom?

Tags: sleep, bedroom, sharing

1. What are the advantages and disadvantages of parents sleeping in the
   same room as their child(ren)? For both parents and child(ren)?
2. Until what age (months? years?) would you prefer to have your child
       sleep in the same room?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We had our daughter in our room until she was 6 months, our son until he as 9 months. The benefits we found were:

1. Night time feeds are a lot easier - it is a lot easier to get the baby
   when they are a few feet away.
2. You only have to heat one room.
3. If the missus needs help for some reason, you are already there.
4. You can hear you child breathing, thus tend to relax a bit more

I can not say there were any downsides aside from having to be quiet when you go to bed. In both cases, we had no issues when we move the children to their own rooms.

Comment: Cool answer. +1